# Can I skip HttpServletRequest.login() and just put authed User in the Session?

Tags: java, jsf-2, servlet-3.0

Assuming i dont have any 'password protected' pages, but sometimes need to know which user clicked some jsf-button, is the below okay, or should I also use HttpServletRequest.login()

some managed bean that handles logins:

```
public void login(String name, String password) {
    try { 
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
        MyUser user = userEjb.login(name, password);
        request.getSession().setAttribute("user", user);
    } catch {
    //login failed message..

    }
}
```

method invoked by h:commandButton:

```
public void doSomething() {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
        MyUser user = request.getSession().getAttribute("user");
        //Is the user object 'safe' here?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the idea, assuming your `login` operation is called at login time and the other snippet is on button press, but I would be careful about what is put in the session.

For example, if the password is persisted in your `MyUser` class, you wouldn't want that stored in the session. The reason why? It is possible to browse sessions from the server, thus the unencrypted password would be visible to a malicous/nosey person with access to your system.

Also what happens if someone accidentally dumps the user object to a web page, or it leaks in an error?

So, given the above paranoia based monologue, my recommendation would be to store a view bean equivalent to your `MyUser` object, which only contains minimal fields, (username, name) for use in your application, e.g., last modified by fields, etc.